# Check the type of user input against known type

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a situation.

I am using wx.textctrl where user needs only to enter a number (positive integers only).
I want to check what the user has entered .
If he has entered a string , i want to do something like this:

```
if type(user_input) == str:
    # do something
```

Or

```
if type(user_input) != int:               
    # do something
```

Actual program looks like

```
ROW = self.Rownum.GetValue()
```

I want to check the type of this `ROW` against string or integer.
Or best will be , if I can force the textctrl box only to accept integers within a range
suppose 1 to 10000 for example.

Comment: I have got a solution . But its a cheap trick.

>>> i=10
>>> if type(i)== type(10):
 print "Yes"
else: print "no"

Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython has Validators for this sort of thing. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/Validator%20for%20Object%20Attributes or [wx.TextCtrl and wx.Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198903/wx-textctrl-and-wx-validator)

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing the user input and then except any errors that turn up.

```
try:
    user_input = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    pass

if type(user_input) == str:
    do something
```