# How to convert alphabetic input in wx.TextCtrl to all capital letters?

Tags: python, validation, wxpython

I am trying to write my first validator for `wx.TextCtrl` based on [this response to another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405979/289572) which should do the following:

> All letters should be printed as captial letters and the text field should only contain captial letters and numbers.

However, my attempts fail in two regards:

- When I change my template (taken from the [linked response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405979/289572)) nothing is added to the text field.
- I cannot change small letters to capital letters.

Here is my attempt:

```
import wx
import string

########################################################################
class CharValidator(wx.PyValidator):
    ''' Validates data as it is entered into the text controls. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, flag):
        wx.PyValidator.__init__(self)
        self.flag = flag
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def Clone(self):
        '''Required Validator method'''
        return CharValidator(self.flag)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def Validate(self, win):
        return True

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnChar(self, event):
        keycode = int(event.GetKeyCode())
        if keycode < 256:
            if keycode > 96 & keycode < 123:
                keycode = keycode - 32
            #print keycode
            key = chr(keycode)
            #print key
            return
        event.Skip()

########################################################################
class ValidationDemo(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Text Validation Tutorial")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        textOne = wx.TextCtrl(panel, validator=CharValidator('no-alpha'))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(textOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ValidationDemo()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all the mess with the validation function is unnecessary. You just need an eventhandler (note that it is sloppy written and is hard coded to the specific `textOne` object instead of takes the input object).

Furthermore, it seems a good idwa to move the `InsertionPoint`:

```
import wx

class ValidationDemo(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Text Validation Tutorial")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.textOne = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.textOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnTextType, self.textOne)

    def OnTextType(self, event):
        self.textOne.ChangeValue(unicode.upper(self.textOne.GetValue()))
        self.textOne.SetInsertionPointEnd()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ValidationDemo()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You should select the answer that answers your posted question and requierements, not your own afterthoughts. In any case, your answer does not address your own posted requierements: first, it does not validate anything just converts to uppercase whatever can be converted, and second, it not complies with your highlighted line "the text field should only contain capital letters and numbers". So I suggest you auto-downvote yourself  :-).

Comment: Perhaps my question was missepcified. I actually dont need a validator. I just want all letters to be in captials. And you are right, the discarding of non digits or characters is not implemented. However, this is what I wanted to achieve. At least it answers the literal question (i.e., headline). I do not want to be rude and really appreciate your answer. But this is the answer I found and I posted it and accepted it as reference (and did not earn any points for it). OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your Demo Frame has some problem with the wxPython widget tree structure.
This will allow you to write in the text control:

```
class ValidationDemo(wx.Frame):
    """"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Text Validation Tutorial")

        textOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, validator=CharValidator('no-alpha'))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(textOne, 1, wx.ALL| wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
```

On the Validator side, you are not sending your letters to the textcontrol once calculated. Still worst, you are always returning and killing the event.

This works (I explain in the comments):

```
def OnChar(self, event):
    keycode = int(event.GetKeyCode())
    #
    # get the widget where the text entry takes place
    object = self.GetWindow()
    #
    # for upper-case and for numbers, let the event go
    if (58 > keycode > 47) or ( 91 > keycode > 64):
        event.Skip()
    #
    # for lower-case, convert to upper and write it yourself
    elif 123 > keycode > 96:
        keycode = keycode - 32
        key = chr(keycode)
        object.write(key)
```

Note I am calling `self.GetWindow()` for each char event. In your case, having one only control using the validator you could define `self.object` only once at validator initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I eventually figured that I don't the validator function but an event handler as you seem to imply as well. See my own answer that implements this.