# WxPython: Control for numbers in scientific notation

Tags: wxpython

Are there controls to allow the user to enter numbers in scientific notation in WxPython? I could not get NumCtrl to accept those, neither have I found a formatter.

Indeed FloatSpin does support scientific notation, but I think a spin control is misleading in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this post myself for future reference.

- lib.masked is not the way to go, since a mask always requires the input to have finite width, which is not guaranteed, as pointed out here:

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/howto-use-validRegex-validFunc-mask-textctrl-td2370136.html

- For me, using wx.PyValidator worked out as desired. 
  Working example with a checkbox (In my case this is suitable but validation can also be triggered by any event):

```
    import wx
    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
            self.box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            self.checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Float?')
            self.txtcontrol = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, validator=FloatValidator())
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX,self.on_checkbox,self.checkbox)
            self.box.Add(self.checkbox,1)
            self.box.Add(self.txtcontrol,1)
            self.SetSizerAndFit(self.box)

            self.Show(True)

        def on_checkbox(self,event):
            if event.GetEventObject().GetValue() and self.Validate():
                print "This is a float!"


    class FloatValidator(wx.PyValidator):
         """ This validator is used to ensure that the user has entered a float
             into the text control of MyFrame.
         """
         def __init__(self):
             """ Standard constructor.
             """
             wx.PyValidator.__init__(self)



         def Clone(self):
             """ Standard cloner.

                 Note that every validator must implement the Clone() method.
             """
             return FloatValidator()

         def Validate(self, win):
             textCtrl = self.GetWindow()
             num_string = textCtrl.GetValue()
             try:
                 float(num_string)
             except:
                 print "Not a float! Reverting to 1e0."
                 textCtrl.SetValue("1e0")
                 return False
             return True


         def TransferToWindow(self):
             """ Transfer data from validator to window.

                 The default implementation returns False, indicating that an error
                 occurred.  We simply return True, as we don't do any data transfer.
             """
             return True # Prevent wxDialog from complaining.


         def TransferFromWindow(self):
             """ Transfer data from window to validator.

                 The default implementation returns False, indicating that an error
                 occurred.  We simply return True, as we don't do any data transfer.
             """
             return True # Prevent wxDialog from complaining.

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, 'Float Test')
    app.MainLoop()
```

The code snippet with the Validator class is taken from

[wx.TextCtrl and wx.Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198903/wx-textctrl-and-wx-validator)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish what you want using a data formatter. There is a wxPython wiki article that actually mentions one using scientific notation here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/DataFormatters

Alternatively, I would recommend looking at matplotlib, which can be easily integrated with wxPython. In fact, someone wrote an article about creating an equation editor in wx here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/MatplotlibEquationEditor

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Writing a data formatter is probably the right way to go.

Comment: I used a validator instead. The formatter class could do this as well, but it is intended to convert interface data to storage data and vice versa.