# Use scientific notation with wxGrid

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am developing a wxpython interface and am wodering if there is a mean to write the numbers in scientific notation in wxGrid.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data formatter or validator should suffice. There is an old article on the wxPython wiki that you can use for inspiration:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/DataFormatters

There is also another StackOverflow question on this topic here:

- [WxPython: Control for numbers in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335722/wxpython-control-for-numbers-in-scientific-notation)

That fellow ended up using a validator to accomplish scientific notation.