# Validate string in TextCtrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

Im written this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
import wx.animate
import wx.lib.agw.hyperlink as hl

ID_BUTTON_ACCEPT = 700
ID_BUTTON_CANCEL = 701
ID_TEXT_INPUT_LOG = 702
ID_TEXT_LABLE_LOG = 703
ID_TEXT_INPUT_PSW = 704
ID_TEXT_LABEL_PSW = 705
ID_NEW_MEMBER_TXT = 706
ID_PRELOADER = 707

class TextObjectValidator(wx.PyValidator):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.PyValidator.__init__(self)

    def Clone(self):
        return TextObjectValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        textCtrl = self.GetWindow()
        text = textCtrl.GetValue()

        if len(text) == 0:
            wx.MessageBox("A text object must contain some text!", "Error")
            textCtrl.SetBackgroundColour("pink")
            textCtrl.SetFocus()
            textCtrl.Refresh()
            return False
        else:
            textCtrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings_GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW))
            textCtrl.Refresh()
            return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True


class CloudStorage(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        # inputs
        self.login_label = wx.StaticText(self, ID_TEXT_LABLE_LOG, label='Логин', pos=(15, 15))
        self.login_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, ID_TEXT_INPUT_LOG, "", size=(210, -1), pos=(75, 10),
                                       validator = TextObjectValidator())
        self.pass_label = wx.StaticText(self, ID_TEXT_LABEL_PSW, label='Пароль', pos=(15, 55))
        self.pass_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, ID_TEXT_INPUT_PSW, size=(210, -1), pos=(75, 50), style=wx.TE_PASSWORD,
                                      validator = TextObjectValidator())

        # buttons
        self.accept_button = wx.Button(self, id=ID_BUTTON_ACCEPT, label='Войти', pos=(15, 95))
        self.accept_button.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        self.accept_button.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")
        self.accept_button.SetFont((wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, 0)))
        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(self, id=ID_BUTTON_CANCEL, label='Отмена', pos=(110, 95))

        # hyperlink to register
        self.new_member_label = hl.HyperLinkCtrl(self, ID_NEW_MEMBER_TXT, 'Зарегистрироваться...', pos=(15,130))
        self.new_member_label.EnableRollover(True)
        self.new_member_label.SetUnderlines(False, False, True)
        self.new_member_label.AutoBrowse(False)
        self.new_member_label.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0))

        # preloader
        self.preloader = wx.animate.AnimationCtrl(self, ID_PRELOADER, pos=(260, 97), size=(24, 24))
        self.preloader.LoadFile('./gui/icons/preloader.gif', wx.animate.ANIMATION_TYPE_GIF)
        self.preloader.Hide()

        # events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRegisterNewUser, id=ID_BUTTON_ACCEPT)
        self.Bind(hl.EVT_HYPERLINK_LEFT, self.OnRegisterNewUser, id=ID_NEW_MEMBER_TXT)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit, id=ID_BUTTON_CANCEL)

        # form settings
        size = (310, 150)
        self.SetSize(size)
        self.icon = wx.Icon('./gui/icons/app.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(self.icon)
        self.Show()

    def PreloaderPlay(self):
        self.preloader.Show()
        self.preloader.Play()

    def PreloaderStop(self):
        self.preloader.Hide()
        self.preloader.Stop()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnRegisterNewUser(self, event):
        self.Hide()

    def OnExitRegister(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnExitFilemanager(self, event):
        self.Close()


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = CloudStorage(None, -1, 'Авторизация')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and want to validate entered data after pressed button "Accept" (on russian is "Войти"), but nothing happens. However, validators will be using in contructors of TextCtrl. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little digging about wxPyvalidators and found an earlier SO question about this : [wx.TextCtrl and wx.Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198903/wx-textctrl-and-wx-validator).

in your `class CloudStorage(wx.Frame)` add this line to :

```
def OnRegisterNewUser(self, event):
    if self.login_input.GetValidator().Validate(self.login_input) and self.pass_input.GetValidator().Validate(self.pass_input):
        self.Hide()
```

Apparently the validator is automatically called if you are using a wx.Dialog. However if you are using a wx.Panel or wx.Frame you have to call the validator method from your event handler. You might also want to read [this](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/validator-not-in-a-dialog-td2373083.html). My understanding may be wrong though. However the code seems to work.

Comment: Just had a similar problem and found your answer is very helpful! Thanks!